# Getting values of multiple columns on the same row of a ListView

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, listview

I have a ListView table and I want the user to be able to select a value in the table and click edit which will open another form for them to edit. What is the best way to pass variables back and fourth and re-populate tables?

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void editSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < basket.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (basket.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                string product = //get product string from table
                string quantity = //get quantity string from table
                string price = //get price string from table
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you bind the view?

Comment: `product = basket.Items[i].SubItems[0]; quantity = basket.Items[i].SubItems[1]; //etc...`

Comment: also, if you have `MultiSelect` set to `false`, you can skip iteration through all items and access selected (sub)items like this: `listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]`

Comment: @Sajeetharan What do you mean?

Comment: how you are setting the datasource to the listview?

Comment: @Sajeetharan When the user runs the form they manually add in the data using the text boxes and the add button at the top of the first form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, To avoid exceptions you should set `MultiSelect` to false,

```
listView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

Form1 (Your main form which contains `ListView`),

```
public ListView _ListView {
     get { return this.listView1; }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
    frm.productName = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].SubItems[0].Text; // set defined variable value (for example, index of subitems 0 represents ProductName)
    frm.Show();    
}
```

And Edit Form's code behind looks like;

```
private Form1 _OpenerForm;
public string productName = "";
public Form2(Form1 OpenerForm)
{
   _OpenerForm = OpenerForm;
   InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = productName;
}

private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    _OpenerForm._ListView.Items[_OpenerForm._ListView.SelectedItems[0].Index].SubItems[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: I have got that working but how can i get the data from the edit form back to the main form and append the data in the ListView?

Comment: Database updated after you have pressed submit button? @kieronoates

Comment: @Berkey how would i pass the values back and re populate the table?

Comment: I am trying to understand now, after you pressed submit button, do you update records at database, where do you keep that values? @kieronoates

Comment: It isnt being stored in a database, it is stored locally in the table and is wiped every time the program is run, if you look at the first image i posted of the Form1 the user enters the data at the top and adds it to the table

Comment: Main form that contains listview. @kieronoates